# Query every between dates every month

Tags: mysql

For example: between 2017-08-29 and 2017-09-29
how do i do this every month not by defining a specific date

Ultimately my goal is to look like this

```
SELECT MONTH, SUM(SALES)
FROM STATUS
WHERE DATE BETWEEN 2017-"MONTH"-29 AND 2017-"MONTH"-29
```

Comment: Please make your question more clear. What the title means?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current month:

```
SELECT MONTH, SUM(SALES)
FROM STATUS
WHERE DATE > LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
AND DATE < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Previous month:

```
SELECT MONTH, SUM(SALES)
FROM STATUS
WHERE DATE > LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
AND DATE < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Do you want a row for every month?